# ubuntu 17.10 cannot install tp-link wn822n

Tags: networking, wireless

Yesterday i made a clean install of Ubuntu 17.10. In order to install aforementioned driver, i use the classic way:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

But when 'make' command is executed. i get a bunch of warnings:

```
~/rtl8192eu-linux-driver$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/build M=/home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_security.o
/home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_security.c: In function ‘aes_cipher’:
/home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_security.c:1598:5: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
     ^~~
/home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_security.c:1601:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
  payload_index = hdrlen + 8;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_security.c: In function ‘aes_decipher’:
/home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_security.c:1984:5: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
     ^~~
/home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_security.c:1987:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
  payload_index = hdrlen + 8;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  CC [M]  /home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_debug.o
  CC [M]  /home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_io.o
  CC [M]  /home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
  CC [M]  /home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
  CC [M]  /home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
  CC [M]  /home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
/home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c: In function ‘rtw_delba_check’:
/home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c:12427:7: warning: this ‘else’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
       else
       ^~~~
/home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c:12429:8: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘else’
        psta->recvreorder_ctrl[i].enable = _FALSE;
        ^~~~
/home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c:12430:7: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
       if (ret != _FAIL)
       ^~
/home/enippeas/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c:12432:8: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
        rtw_reset_continual_no_rx_packet(psta, i);

 ...... and so on
```

Note that the 'classic way' worked flawlessly for Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.04. I'm struggling a whole day to make it work with no success. I would appreciate any help

Comment: You shouldn't need that source code using 17.10 see https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665 and paste the contents of the wireless-info.txt file at paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL

Comment: thanks Jeremy for reply. Url is  https://paste.ubuntu.com/26501940/

Comment: weird.. after repeated restarts seems to work but no flashing at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wifi device is supported in kernel 4.13 with module rtl8xxxu and you might benefit by blacklisting the module you built as it did load

```
echo "blacklist 8192eu" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

You wifi router is using TKIP encryption and that can cause issues in Ubuntu, it would be preferred to use WPA2 only for encryption